# Can an ellipse roll down a tilted sine curve without jumping?

Tags: trigonometry, mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations

**Background**

Assume that we have a solid ellipse with uniform density, and that it rolls along a curve.

In the following [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418486/along-what-curve-does-an-ellipse-roll-down-the-fastest), I asked along what curve an ellipse rolls down fastest. It was pointed out that one first needs to find *any* curve the ellipse rolls down from, without losing contact from the curve and jumping up and down. One can consider this as a variation of the classical [Brachistochrone problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachistochrone_curve).

Now, it turns out that there are various curves along which an ellipse can roll *horizontally*. These are described in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0aOxj5lrKY) by Morphocular. It turns out that, if one wants to describe the equation of the curve along which an ellipse with width $2a$ and height $2b$ rolls down horizontally with the center as its axle point, the x-coordinate of this equation comes down to an [elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) (see 5:04 of the video):

$$x = \int \frac{b}{\sqrt{1-\epsilon^{2} \cos^{2}(\theta)}} d \theta \label{1}\tag{1} $$

This is not an easy expression to deal with. However, there is a way out if one chooses the foci as the axle points, instead of the center of the ellipse. Assume that the ellipse has width $1$ and height $\sqrt{2}$. In this case, we can describe the curve with a simple sine wave, with period $\pi$ and amplitude $1/2$. Here is a picture (a snapshot from the video at 7:39):

[image]

The equation of this curve can thus be described succinctly as $$y = \frac{1}{2} \sin(2x) .\label{2}\tag{2}$$

**Question**

Now, suppose that we tilt this sine curve and the ellipse by an angle of $\theta$. In the image below, I have visualized the setting. (Note that the shape of the sine curve is different from the one above. However, this is merely due to my mediocre illustration skills. It is supposed to describe the same curve as the one shown in the image above. The same applies to the ellipse.)

[image]

I have the following questions:

1. For what values of $\theta$ does the curve roll down without losing contact with the tilted sine curve - if any?
2. If there are multiple values of $\theta$ for which the ellipse rolls down properly, I wonder: for what value does the ellipse roll down the fastest?

Comment: Is this a solid ellipse with uniform density, or is the mass all on the boundary (perhaps uniformly distributed with respect to arc length), or what?  I suspect this will affect the dynamics.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, it is a solid ellipse with uniform density. I have clarified this now in the question.